# Quickly count how many words a letter shows up in

Tags: php

I have an array of words, I need to figure out how many words each letter shows up in. The number of times per word doesn't matter, only the number of words.

I only need to check on `a-z`, but since the array of words can be quite large (over 100,000) at a time, 26 iterations through the whole loop will take far too long for this.

What's a quicker way to check this? 260,000 loops is far too many for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to loop through all the words, you could use `count_chars` to give you all the unique letters used in each word quickly... but other than that there isn't much you can do. You can either test all letters against a word `str_split` and `array_unique`, or you can split the word into letters and find the unique ones `count_chars`.

EDIT: If you are looking for absolute performance then you simply have to try all the different combinations. Point being, algorithm-wise, there isn't much one can do if your data is dynamic or "unknown".

Comment: Id also go with the array_filter function as an option but I think that would be the same performance as just looping through each word.